# Porque le asigno un valor a un objeto y me retorna 0?

Tags: javascript

```js
class Coin{
  constructor(){
    this.price = 0.00;
    this.total = 0.00;
  }
}

function main(){
  const coin= new Coin();
  price(coin);
  ver(coin);
}

function price(coin){
  var cont = 0.00;
  var tot = 0.00;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data_response){  
      tot += parseFloat(data_response.last_price);
      cont++;
      coin.price = (tot/cont);
      transform(coin);
    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log*d
    }
  });
}

  function transform(coin){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/1ACAgPuFFidYzPMXbiKptSrwT74Dg8hq2v',
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data_response){  
            coin.total += parseFloat(data_response * Math.pow(10,-8));
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });   
  }

  function ver(coin){
      console.log(coin.total);
  }

  main();
```

Quisiera saber porque me devuelve 0 si el total lo modifique anteriormente.

Comment: Bienvenido. En la función price, la línea `console.log*d` devuelve error `d` está definido. Es probable que cuando la corrijas veas un error en la consola.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es cambiar el valor de `coin` , deberías declararla como una variable, no como una constante;

Así:

```
var coin = new Coin();
```

de ésta manera puedes alterar su valor durante la ejecución del programa.

Al ser llamadas asincronas, deberías llamar al método ver en el success de tu ultima llamada ajax:

```
 function transform(coin){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/1ACAgPuFFidYzPMXbiKptSrwT74Dg8hq2v',
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data_response){  
            coin.total += parseFloat(data_response * Math.pow(10,-8));
            ver(coin);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });   
  }
```

tu main quedaría así:

```
function main(){
  const coin= new Coin();
  price(coin);
}
```

Comment: Ya probe cambiandolo a var y tampoco

Comment: el ajax te devuelve valores distintos de 0 ?

Comment: si y lo que quiero es ver el total al final

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
function main(){
  const coin= new Coin();
  price(coin);
  ver(coin);
}
```

La funcion price() genera dos llamadas Ajax las cuales son asincronicas.  Cuando llamas a la funcion ver(), las dos llamadas todavia no han retornado.  Si quieres ver el resultado correcto, mueve la llamada a ver() dentro del success() de la ultima llamada Ajax.

Comment: el problema seria si tengo varias monedas y desearia ver todas las monedas, tendria que pasar el arreglo siempre que use la funcion price()

Comment: Si tienes un arreglo de monedas y quieres verlas todas a la vez entonces si tendrias que pasarlo

Comment: tengo un arreglo de monedas y quisiera verlas al final del programa

Comment: Podrias pasar el arreglo y hacer un loop iterando por cada una, a menos que la api permita pasar varias monedas a la vez

Comment: Si lo hago en un loop me tira problemas de undefined o que no puede leer cierta variable